# AXI Stream using Vivado

Tags: vivado

I have a Xilinx Zybo board. I followed the instructions [here](http://www.fpgadeveloper.com/2014/08/creating-a-custom-ip-block-in-vivado.html) and created a custom multiplier over the AXI-Lite bus. Now I want to use the multiplier over AXI-Stream bus so that I can continuously send inputs, and get outputs. How can I do this? will I need to add a DMA controller as well?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need a DMA controller.

There are two kinds of AXI bus: AXI stream and AXI memory. (AXI memory is just a grouping of three AXI streams — address/command, write data and read data.) AXI Lite is just a particular configuration of an AXI memory bus. In order to transfer data from AXI memory to AXI stream (or vice-versa), you need to use a DMA controller.

Comment: Any tutorials that you know of that I can follow?